# Optimize content heavy HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm managing a site that does online courses with classes giveon on an HTML page.
Each class is on it's own page and it is NOT possible to split the class on multiple pages.
My problem is that the browsers grind to a halt on loading the classes.
There are about 2000 DOM elements, 100 of which are images, about 2 PDF documents (in the 200k-20MB range), and 1 to 3 youtube videos.

What can I do to make the site load "progressively" ? If I were to print the classes (there's a print button) it'd take between 20 to 60 pages.
Here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEwHu.jpg) is a screenshot of one of the entries

Text smudged because they are somewhat private

Comment: 1st thing to do is to check that IMG and all other embeddable HTML tags have size defined. 2000 DOM elements are not that much if they are all easily renderable. But definedly you want to have progressive loading. This could be just quick check to go forward.

Comment: All IMG elements have their size defined. The largest pages do reach over 4k DOM elements but they are few. On my desktop computer there's no problem but I've gotten a few complaints from people on ultrabooks

Answer (score 1):

You can try 'progressive loading' techniques.

http://docforge.com/wiki/Web_application/Progressive_loading

Its not however simple to do. You need to have more knowledge in JavaScript to perform this efficiently.
There are lot of libraries available to do so.

But, first get idea about progressive loading techinques

http://www.slideshare.net/stoyan/progressive-downloads-and-rendering